# Unable to determine value for user.home: No error

Tags: fortify

I have installed fortify and when I run below from CLI , I get below error :

C:\X\X\X>sourceanalyzer

Unable to determine value for user.home: No error

Could someone please advise.

Thanks
Vishal Chugh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get this error, Fortify is not able to acquire the path to the Desktop folder.  Instead of using the proper way of looking this up, either Fortify or the provided JRE is looking at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Desktop` for the path.  This is a deprecated method and should not be used.

The fix is to populate the above registry key appropriately.  Once you do this, Fortify will start working.